# RAD Studio Sydney で、Android実機にプログラムがインストールできなくなった

Tags: android, delphi, rad-studio

RAD Studio SydneyのFMXでビルドすると、これまではAndroid実機にプログラムがインストールされて、動作していました。sydneyのパッチをあててからは、AABファイルが作成されるだけで、Android実機で動作しなくなりました。原因がよくわかりません。対処方法をご存じでしたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

お使いのDelphiのバージョンは10.4.2で、そこにRAD Studio 10.4.2 General Patch/Delphi 10.4.2 Compiler Patch/Delphi 10.4.2 RTL Patchの3つを適用したらAndroid端末にデプロイできなくなった、ということですか？
ちなみに手元の環境では上記の組み合わせでデバッグ実行、デバッグなしの実行とも問題なく動作しています。
単純な(メインフォームだけの)プロジェクトを作って試してみるとどうでしょう？またIDEになにかメッセージは表示されていないでしょうか？
(あとこの質問のタグにdelphiを追加したほうがよさそうです)